# Develop Go application that access to Windows

Tags: windows, go

I am downloading MinGW to compile Go in Windows but, is it necessary any SDK to develop Go applications that access to Windows' system calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You don't need anything else than the standard library and windows compiler to run Go code on Windows. Including syscalls.

Check out the [`syscall`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package in Go's standard library.